# Will small files be spread across partitions in JavaPairRDD?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

This may be a silly question, but I'm not able to understand how the files are split across partitions.
My requirement is to read 10000 Binary files(Bloom filter persisted file) from Hdfs location and process the Binary files separately by converting the data to ByteArrayInputStream . The point to be noted is these files are Bloom filter persisted files and should be read sequentially from the start of the file till to the end and should be converted to Byte Array, thus this Byte array will be used to restructure the Bloomfilter object.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, PortableDataStream> rdd = sparkContext.binaryFiles(commaSeparatedfilePaths);

rdd.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream>, BloomCheckResponse>()
```

Here in the code, I get v1._1 as Filepath and v1._2 the PortableDataStream which will be converted to ByteArrayInputStream.
Each binary file is of 34 MB.
Now the question is will there come a situation where part of the file will be in one partition and the other part in a different one? Or all the time I process, will I get all the content of file mapped to its file in single partition and its not split across?
Executor memory = 4GB and the cores = 2 and the executors are 180.
Basically the expectation is that the file should be read the way it is from start to end without split.

Answer (score 0):

Each `(file, stream)` is guaranteed to provide full content of the `file` in the `stream`. There is no case where data will be divided between multiple pairs, not to mention multiple partitions.

You're safe to use it for your intended scenario.

Comment: I understand that the data will not be spark across multiple pairs. But my concern is mainly will the data be split across partitions or will the data be jumbled for whatever reason it is. cuz file should be read the same way it is written else the Object creation of the content will be a problem.